# @font-face custom font not showing in windows using chrome

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, fonts, font-face

Link to site i'm working on: http://ji83plus.com/

For some reason my custom font isn't working on windows using chrome. Works fine in internet explorer on the same device.

Also works on my Mac in Chrome and Safari. Seems to work fine on my tablet/phone aswell using both chrome and safari.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the embedded code you used for font

Comment: You will need to embed an `.eot` and a `.ttf` font. If you dont have one of these, ask the man who made it or use a converter online.